# Transpose rows to columns as it is in SQL Server (T-SQL) or SSIS without losing data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, pivot, transpose

The current & expected table data is attached.

Current SQL Server table `Src_Tbl`:

```
ID                                      Name    Value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    author  Raghav Mishra
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    title   The First Article to SSC
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    genre   Fiction
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    price   200
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    pub_date    1/31/2013
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    review  Interesting book
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    author  Vasanth Mishra
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    title   The First Article to SSC
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    genre   Fiction
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    price   90
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    pub_date    1/29/2013
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    review  fiction book
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    author  Vinoth Mishra
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    title   The First Article to SSC
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    genre   Fiction
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    price   150
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    pub_date    1/30/2013
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    review  Good book
```

After transpose, it should look like this:

```
ID                                      author          title                       genre     price     pub_date    review
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    Raghav Mishra   The First Article to SSC    Fiction     200     1/31/2013   Interesting book
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    Vasanth Mishra  The First Article to SSC    Fiction      90     1/29/2013   fiction book
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069    Vinoth Mishra   The First Article to SSC    Fiction     150     1/30/2013   Good book
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT Name, Value
     FROM dbo.Src_Tbl) AS Src 
PIVOT
    (MAX(Value) FOR Name IN (author, title, genre, price, pub_date, review)) AS PivotTable;
```

Since `Pivot()` function mandates use of aggregate function, it limits the rows (data is lost).

I get only one record which is not my need. I need a direct transpose.

Even if I try using some case statement with group by same issue have to aggregate. This is the problem statement and is the client requirement from a dataset [simple transpose).

Is there any way to get this done in SSIS / T-SQL / SQL Server?

I need the result output from Src_Tbl.

I have to use SQL Server for this, T-SQL procedure or SSIS.

On a side note, I am really surprised why there is no provision to do a straight transpose like how we copy paste in excel.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, so you cannot control what matches what in the result set -- unless you data has more columns with that information.

Comment: If `Src_Tbl` is already in your database, then it's order is already lost. If it came from an external source, then you can recover that order.

Comment: How do I order it using sql? I would need to create a groupid using tsql. Any ideas? is it feasible? grouping based on repeating data paterns here in this case,author,title,genre,price,pubdate,review are repeating data pattern. how to add a groupid column based on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to reproduce order with fictitious row_number and after that identify groups by adding new column with row_number(). Ofc, it's not the way you should store your data (try to use primary keys, providing correct order for your data), but I hope, it will help:

```
WITH Src_Tbl AS (
    SELECT
         t.ID
        ,t.Name
        ,t.Value
    FROM (VALUES
        ('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'author', 'Raghav Mishra')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'title', 'The First Article to SSC')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'genre', 'Fiction')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'price', '200')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'pub_date', '1/31/2013')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'review', 'Interesting book')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'author', 'Vasanth Mishra')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'title', 'The First Article to SSC')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'genre', 'Fiction')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'price', '90')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'pub_date', '1/29/2013')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'review', 'fiction book')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'author', 'Vinoth Mishra')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'title', 'The First Article to SSC')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'genre', 'Fiction')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'price', '150')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'pub_date', '1/30/2013')
        ,('9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069', 'review', 'Good book')

    ) t (ID, Name, Value)
)
SELECT
*
FROM (
    SELECT
         t.ID
        ,t.Name
        ,t.Value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, Name ORDER BY t.RN_for_correct_order) AS RN
    FROM (
        SELECT
             t.ID
            ,t.Name
            ,t.Value
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(1, 1)) AS RN_for_correct_order -- try to get same order as in example
        FROM Src_Tbl t
    ) t
) t
PIVOT
    (MAX(Value) FOR Name IN (author, title, genre, price, pub_date, review)) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: this would work if we group it. but still returns one result since there is Max.. the issue is aggregation..was thinking to order like below using sql but how? ID Name Value groupid
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069 author Raghav Mishra 1
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069 title The First Article to SSC 1
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069 genre Fiction 1
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069 price 200 1
9C8AA305-5977-4803-8C5F-E0E8665B9069 pub_date 1/31/2013 1

next group id 2

Comment: Yes, you are right, just add some identification of group to your query such as row_number. I've edited my answer, please check if it's ok.

Comment: now data is not lost but the values get mapped incorrectly. author linked to incorrect price. title mapped incorrect author... .i think order by value is causing this...

Comment: Yes, as it's already mentioned in comments under your question, if you don't have a clustered index on your table, you data as stored in a heap, but you can try to reproduce a correct order with something like row_number() over "nothing". Please check my edited answer with sql for your example.